# How to get a list of dict that each dict is coming from the same original dict with only one key removed?

Tags: python, json, loops

My scenario:
I need to iterate through a nested json object, get return a list of json object, each has one key removed. And you don't know how the original data are structured.

As far as I go:
I wrote a recursion function to print every key value in the object. It works. But this is not what I want.

**Define return:**
This function gets a dict and returns a list of dict, each dict is a  copy of the original dict after one key removed.

If the dict has 3 keys from the beginning, then I should get 3 dicts each has 1 key removed.

And yes if the key has nested value, they should be removed as well. For example if the key happens to be the root key, then it remains an empty dict.

Here's my code:

```
def iterate_keys(data: dict):
    # This is as far as I can go
    for key, value in data.items():
        if type(value) in [dict, ]:
            iterate_keys(value)
        elif type(value) in [list, ]:
            for item in value:
                if type(item) in [dict]:
                    iterate_keys(item)
        print(key, value)

# def what_i_really_want(data: dict) -> list:
    # return [dict1, dict2, ...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_dict = {
        "a": "a",
        "c": {
            "c1": [
                {"c11": "c11"},
                {"c12": "c12"},
            ]
        },
    }

    iterate_keys(test_dict)
```

For the test_dict in the code, ideally it should return list dicts like blow.

```
result_should_be = [
        {
            # with "a" removed
            "c": {
                "c1": [
                    {"c11": "c11"},
                    {"c12": "c12"},
                ]
            }
        },
        # with "c11" removed
        {
            "a": "a",
            "c": {
                "c1": [
                    {"c12": "c12"},
                ]
            }
        },
        # with "c12" removed
        {
            "a": "a",
            "c": {
                "c1": [
                    {"c11": "c11"},
                ]
            }
        },
        # with "c1" removed
        {
            "a": "a",
            "c": {}
        },
        # with "c" removed
        {
            "a": "a"
        },
    ]
```

**At the end of the day, I'm creating a bunch of test cases.**
Hope I made myself clear

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Why not use `import json` and `json.load(test_dict)` then you can modify keys and values just through python code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add more information on what I expected. Because I don't have a specific key to remove, I need a set in which every item is a copy of this json object with only one  key modified

Comment: Are you trying to write a function which removes a predefined set of keys from the json?

Comment: Not predefined. Assume JSON object has 10 keys in total.  I'm trying to create 10 objects, each of them has one key removed. If the object has 100 keys then I need to create 100 objects.

Comment: I want to help but need more details. Will the output be another JSON or a list? Will nested keys be removed as well? The requirements are not clear enough - maybe it will be a good idea to start with defining what you want more rigorousy.

Comment: Thank you all for commenting. First, output doesnt really matter, preferably one json at a time. Second, nested keys will be removed as well.  I will edit my question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have really been struggling with this. Somehow I managed to solve it with two libraries.

The first one [jsonpathgenerator](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpathgenerator/) gets me all the jsonpath of my original data. It orginally gave me all the 'leaf' item's jsonpath. So I changed the source code a little bit to get every key's jsonpath.

The second one jsonpath_ng let me filter a key with jsonpath.

And with a little bit data manipulation I got the result I was looking for.

This is for if someone ever run into the same situation as me.